# json_encode error for special characters in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, json

In checkout page in magento. In billing information when i select a country, states having special characters are not displayed.For ex: **A Coruña,Ardèche** .I got this error message in error.log

```
Warning: json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in /chroot/home/site/html/lib/Zend/Json.php on line 146.
```

Is there any solution to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be all character is UTF8, but json_encode does not handle it correctly.

here is a list of [other characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex) (see Unicode characters list)

that will trigger the same error, so stripping off this one like (Å)

try below this could be help you.

```
htmlentities( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE);
```

Comment: In which file i want to add this ?

Answer (score 1):

worth to check in this class `Mage_Directory_Helper_Data`

In `billing.phtml` file   this code update state selection dropdown 
`var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');`

So change in this function `_getRegions($storeId)` as suggested by  **Mr Liyakat**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the value being encoded to json is not UTF-8 encoded data. PHP function json_encode, unfortunately, will only accept UTF-8 as its parameter.

You can try something like below

```
$state = mb_check_encoding($state, 'UTF-8') ? $state : utf8_encode($state);
```

before submitting the form.

I havn't tested it, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Where i want to add this code?

Comment: I am not sure but I guess, in billing.phtml in onepagecheckout

Answer (score 0):

make sure the translation file itself was explicitely stored as UTF-8

After that reload cache blocks and translations